# How to set date on a iOS jailbroken device programmatically?

Tags: ios, datetime, automated-tests, jailbreak

I'm running automated tests for iOS applications. One of those tests require me to change the device date in order to fulfill the test preconditions. I understand that this is not possible for a non-jailbroken device and also this won't be sent to the Apple Store, it is just a specific usage scenario for this automated test case. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing iPhone's date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278450/changing-iphones-date-and-time)

Comment: @shallowThought Alright, but that's a different problem, and also [one that has been answered already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43962260).

Comment: @shallowThought, there's no point in combining because linking against private frameworks is, a) different question, b) common knowledge when dealing with private APIs. Also, it doesn't matter how old my answer is. Check if it works first before rejecting a perfectly valid and thoroughly written answer. It was not accepted probably because it requires jailbreak to work

Comment: @creker Good point.